# View/set laptop power settings on a VM (desktop)

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, imaging

I'm building a reference windows image in a VM and I want to tweak the power settings. Windows identifies the VM as a desktop and only presents me with the standard desktop power settings.

Is there any way for me to view the full set power settings, escpecially the on battery vs. on charger settings, that one would typically see on a laptop so that I can tweak them to our needs and capture them in the image.

Comment: If there is no battery detected, you won't be able to configure Windows, to use a power.  Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Because I'm building a reference windows image for use in deployment across laptops and desktops

Comment: Do you know how to add your own power plans? [How to Change Power Plan Settings in Windows](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/5464-power-plan-settings-change-windows-8-a.html)

Comment: Be sure you read the entire article, it explains how you can set the default behavior, for those options that are not available.

Comment: Unfortunately the option shown there (where you are able to view settings from a different power mode) isn't available in Win 7.

Comment: You never said you were using Windows 7....

Comment: Sorry, figured that tagging the question as win 7 was enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up doing it through powercfg. It gives you access to all options regardless of whether the option is valid for the current machine.

The specific command I used was

```
powercfg -Change -standby-timeout-ac 0
```

Through the -change command in powercfg you can modify all settings including the ones that aren't currently visible to you because the system doesn't support them.